# DB2 restrict analytic function to subselect

Tags: sql, db2, olap

I often encountered the situation where I wanted to restrict the action of an analytic function (or OLAP in DB2) to a certain subset of the present data. Here is an example:

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS
(
     SELECT 1 AS FIELD1, 'A' AS FIELD2,  1 AS FIELD3, 'X' AS FIELD4 FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT 1 AS FIELD1, 'A' AS FIELD2, 2 AS FIELD3, 'Y' AS FIELD4 FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT 1 AS FIELD1, 'B' AS FIELD2, 3 AS FIELD3, 'X' AS FIELD4 FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT 1 AS FIELD1, 'A' AS FIELD2, 4 AS FIELD3, 'Z' AS FIELD4 FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT 1 AS FIELD1, 'B' AS FIELD2, 5 AS FIELD3, 'Z' AS FIELD4 FROM DUAL
     //...
)
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(FIELD4) OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1 ORDER BY FIELD3) AS FIELD2_A
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE FIELD2='A'  // need that as well for 'B', 'C' etc.
```

Now it is cumbersome to do this for all required values of `FIELD2` and afterwards doing a JOIN or a UNION, moreover since the constraints might be more complicated.

Thus I really want to handle it in a single SELECT. Here is a trial:

```
//...
SELECT CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 'A'
            THEN FIRST_VALUE(FIELD4)
                       OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1
                             ORDER BY CASE WHEN FIELD2='A' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, FIELD3)
            ELSE NULL END AS FIELD4_A,
       CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 'B'
            THEN FIRST_VALUE(FIELD4)
                       OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1
                             ORDER BY CASE WHEN FIELD2='B' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, FIELD3)
            ELSE NULL END AS FIELD4_B,
      //a bit more complicated 
      CASE WHEN FIELD2 IN ('A','C')
            THEN FIRST_VALUE(FIELD4)
                       OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1
                             ORDER BY CASE WHEN FIELD2 IN ('A','C') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, FIELD3)
            ELSE NULL END AS FIELD4_AC
FROM MY_TABLE
```

The idea is to order the data set by the WHERE-criterion, but since there might be cases where rows with such a constraint do not exist in the partition (and thus the unwanted result would be obtained), a non-null value is returned only if the `FIELD2` meets the constraint (this is done in the outer `CASE` statement).

I guess this approach works (--I haven't tested it yet), but it is a bit detoured. **Are there easier or more direct approaches to accomplish the above task?**

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(FIELD4) OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1, FIELD2 ORDER BY FIELD3) AS FIELD2_A
FROM MY_TABLE
```

If you want this pivoted into separate columns:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 'A'
             THEN FIRST_VALUE(FIELD4) OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1, FIELD2 ORDER BY FIELD3) 
        END) as FIELD4_A,
       (CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 'B'
             THEN FIRST_VALUE(FIELD4) OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1, FIELD2 ORDER BY FIELD3) 
        END) as FIELD4_B,
```

EDIT:

I suspect that you want to pivot the "first" values.  If it can never be `NULL`, then this might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 'A' THEN FIELD4 END IGNORE NULLS) OVER
           (PARTITION BY FIELD1, FIELD2 ORDER BY FIELD3) as FIELD4_A,
       FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 'B' THEN FIELD4 END IGNORE NULLS) OVER
           (PARTITION BY FIELD1, FIELD2 ORDER BY FIELD3) as FIELD4_B,
. . .
```

Comment: Partitioning by the constrainted field doesn't work directly, because the constraints can be more complicated than this (I mentioned that in the question but it obviously didn't get clear). For example, in another line one could want the corresponding result where `FIELD2 IN ('A', 'C')`. One could then of course use `PARTITION BY CASE WHEN FIELD2 IN ('A', 'C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`, but this is no improvement over the given example in the OP (which uses the same in the `ORDER BY` statement). There are still 2 very similar `CASE`-statements in the query.

Comment: Your EDIT looks like the kind of advice I was looking for. It contains merely a single `CASE` statement. Thanks.

Comment: In DB2 LUW 10.1, the corresponding command is `FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN FIELD2 = 'A' THEN FIELD4 END, 'IGNORE NULLS')`.